# How can i zip and download complete folder from aws s3 in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3

I've just started storing all the files i need for my website in AWS S3, I've uploaded all the files and now i want to create a function so that i can allow a user to download all the files in a folder with a single click.
I want to take all the files inside the bucket folder, zip them into one file and then download. And i want all of this to happen on browser side  on front end.

I've been stuck on this problem for a couple of days. And i could really use some help. I am completely new to S3